How can i get all the cookies using requests in python?
I need help to get all the cookies I would get from a page using a webdriver, but using requests. I'm trying to get info from a page. In this case there are some cookies that I think are being loaded by Javascript, also some of them are Akamai cookies. I don't need to get the valid akamai cookies, just all the cookies a regular user would get.
Need this to be made by request in Python. This is my code
import tls_client
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
import time

url = "https://www.fansale.at/tickets/all/taylor-swift/502069/17337901"


normal_header = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'priority': 'u=0, i',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}



s = tls_client.Session(
    ja3_string="771,4865-4866-4867-49195-49199-49196-49200-52393-52392-49171-49172-156-157-47-53,0-23-65281-10-11-35-16-5-13-18-51-45-43-27-17513,29-23-24,0",
    h2_settings={
        "HEADER_TABLE_SIZE": 65536,
        "MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS": 1000,
        "INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE": 6291456,
        "MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE": 262144
    },
    h2_settings_order=[
        "HEADER_TABLE_SIZE",
        "MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS",
        "INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE",
        "MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE"
    ],
    supported_signature_algorithms=[
        "ECDSAWithP256AndSHA256",
        "PSSWithSHA256",
        "PKCS1WithSHA256",
        "ECDSAWithP384AndSHA384",
        "PSSWithSHA384",
        "PKCS1WithSHA384",
        "PSSWithSHA512",
        "PKCS1WithSHA512",
    ],
    supported_versions=["GREASE", "1.3", "1.2"],
    key_share_curves=["GREASE", "X25519"],
    cert_compression_algo="brotli",
    pseudo_header_order=[
        ":method",
        ":authority",
        ":scheme",
        ":path"
    ],
    connection_flow=15663105,
    header_order=[
        "accept",
        "user-agent",
        "accept-encoding",
        "accept-language"
    ]
)



def first():
    if cookiess != None:
        s.get(url=url, headers=normal_header, cookies=cookiess)
    else:
        s.get(url=url, headers=normal_header)

    cookies = s.cookies
    abck = cookies['_abck']
    bm_sz = cookies['bm_sz']
    
    for cookie in cookies:
        print(cookie)
    return abck, bm_sz, cookies

abck, bm_sz, cookies = first()

These are the cookies I get
<Cookie JSESSIONID=D9D8DFDCCB61FD164417EA5520119FA5 for www.fansale.at/>
<Cookie AF=FAU for www.fansale.at/>
<Cookie fansale.LOCALE=de for www.fansale.at/>
<Cookie access.FANSALE=1720613405427 for www.fansale.at/>
<Cookie BIGipServer~WEB~tickets.fansale.de=rd1o00000000000000000000ffff0ac01076o80 for www.fansale.at/>
<Cookie bm_ss=ab8e18ef4e for .fansale.at/>
<Cookie _abck=6C695C63673CA1C6F04D815ECFA8D6D6~-1~YAAQkLU+F+dSkZeQAQAAyASNnAy9u0gXFuOozKEyr8JHjMR/JFf4n35k9Z3RrcujPXrI4aRzBwAn83a8OWynAr7H4Dh6l6SSt3OmkWd8Mkn8WrQ50nBiYfSi3G0l4NSVgVN7a4AikBqZWd4Edx3pzw4XBEdqwiifOBBEvKKxXSN+F/LmB7ppFxD5cfbQIH5CU1mjR84PiPncnrobCyicZN7f8A1TxtKRlLo2L2+mu0PsYi9ycb8LNX68WW/I7+aububqRbry108rgBvK4+LyccUBC8D711CvlfMaopdt1sJgXrxtXI+1gwE/POby9JNFrOVuE46MuEGKAuywfeTKCNCXrxMIbhnlrC81vmaMs1B2Ntus52YxBMfIEXk=~-1~-1~-1 for .fansale.at/>
<Cookie bm_s=YAAQkLU+F+lSkZeQAQAAyASNnAFyqFdz+klvS87THs6V47N+V7XWYMqlWy7UFi2E1cbY4yRsOqah42kIV+Ozg6oKsscV1PCSzKxoxM4SbRIOKpx6xoUJFYvPLo0B4gMAQijPyDo/2TyLOV9/PItd1WyKx5lWFTeJYV4O+QwU0QtFcdBKMuNBYk4ftjjKwoqlO2+JphWkVcNll4tqCKIDUQyiTHnEeQJFzatXteF7i0ZjAKnXUU0nUz6b5olcv+Zr94DBo9CB///4VyXWEShxAaS1m6GY75JZWCaD6ekMjrP9Kzf/pfLsRBUHT2OHVr3/Gthprpc/n2RTgZcEi6+XUCUf7jeqrA== for .fansale.at/>
<Cookie bm_sz=7A57F29FE33909B1B1E81E72A6E222DC~YAAQkLU+F+pSkZeQAQAAyASNnBiBclzLAxuztgw8YQ+XGveCtUMIf15E32hSY8oiWro7u0hB1n4AcK9YgHFt8Q6PJel3ZP9W04Tlo+LpGzIqrNbPLxZtRj3rUCtk4xm994WkHopSFHiSQHy9krDhv4aTRboEYU4SucMo0q2akEgVKJ4NFJXUiTCurnlMfOIDalLOpTINMga6Ivy1FFrzylfjZvVy12VnhgkKO5IWVW4rG8KeZ7SmsTy+hs0tm4jIMCrLT5ZqzVrIhtJgmEWqlO5iIeB/r4258XmzLgF0YXn1cShcB3CJeeX+63h5AT4npTfdUAQ9SH01Gir9/Ow8C2UXt1Bh9kixEZnOYaepmhjVy8+LApOD5U6bhkLGhS53IcAL6u9RGQ==~3420997~3360321 for .fansale.at/>

I did a request with tls_client defined with its orders, but I don't actually know if they are good, and tried to get all cookies apart from Akamai ones, but it just returns some of them.

"In this case there are some cookies that I think are being loaded by Javascript" - then you obviously won't be able to get those, by just requesting the source code via HTTP - the JavaScript needs to actually get executed. You might want to check How can I scrape a page with dynamic content (created by JavaScript) in Python?

Yes, you are right, many cookies are loaded via javascript. Do I understand you correctly, you need to see a list of all possible cookies that the site can set? Or do you need specifically the cookies that are installed?
